# Racket count occurrences using `map`

Tags: scheme, racket, map-function

> Write a Racket function `count-occurrences` that consumes two lists of symbols and produces a list of
>   natural numbers measuring how many times items in the first list occur in the second list. For example:
>
> ```
> (count-occurrences (list 'a 'b 'a 'q) (list 'r 'a 'b 'e 'b 'g))
> ```
>
> => (list 1 2 1 0)

I've been struggling with this question - how do I use `map` to do it, since for this question it's specified we can't use recursion.

My original idea was to do the following:

```
(define (count-occurrences los1 los2) 
  (map
   (length (filter (lambda (x) (symbol=? x (first los1))) los2))
   los1))
```

but using `length` here can only get us the number 'a occurred, instead of going into recursion. and for abstract functions there can only be one argument for the inside function, so I'm totally lost.

Comment: what have you tried? do please show anything you have.

Comment: Start with writing a function that counts the occurrences of *one* given symbol in a list of symbols. Then think about how you can use that function.

Comment: With SRFI-26 and SRFI-1 it's almost a one liner. What part of the problem is it that you are unsure about?

Comment: Hint: `map`'s first argument should be a procedure. Since `length` produces a numeric result, `(map num lst)` will give you a `map: contract violation` error.

Answer (score 3):

If `... x ...` is an *open formula*, i.e. an expression which references an *unbound* variable `x`, wrapping it in a `lambda` form makes it a function in `x`, like so:

```
(lambda (x) ... x ... )
```

where `x` becomes *bound* by that lambda form; a *parameter* to this so called lambda function, which is to say, an anonymous function introduced by a `lambda` form.

So, the solution for your troubles is quite simple: recognize that

```
    (length
        (filter (lambda (x)               
                     (symbol=? x (first los1)))
                los2))
```

should actually be

```
    (length
        (filter (lambda (x)               
                     (symbol=? x y))
                los2))
```

where `y` refers to *each* of the elements of `los1` in turn, *not* just the first one; and that it is then an open formula in `y` – that is to say, `y` is unbound, *free*, there. So we must capture it, and make it bound, by ... yes, enclosing this expression in a `lambda` form, thereby making it a function *in* `y`! Like so:

```
  (lambda (y)
    (length
        (filter (lambda (x)               
                     (symbol=? x y))
                los2)))
```

And *this* is what gets mapped over `los1`.

With this simple tweak, your code becomes a correct, working function definition.

Answer (score 1):

Does this fit your requirements and restrictions?

```
(define (count-occurrences lst1 lst2)
  (map (lambda (e1)
         (count (lambda (e2) (eq? e1 e2))
                lst2))
       lst1))
```

Comment: Why `eq?` rather than `equal?`?  `eq?` has some surprising failure cases.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to keep track of keys and values is with a hash-table. While it is possible to write `count-occurrences` using `map` and passing a `lambda`, being explicit may make it easier to see what is going on.

```
;;; list list -> list
;;; 
(define (count-occurrences keys values)

  ;; Create data structure
  (define ht (make-hash))

  ;; Initialize data structure with keys
  ;; Set the value of each key to zero
  ;; Since we have not started counting
  (for ([k keys])
    (hash-set! ht k 0))

  ;; Iterate over values and
  ;; Increment hash table if
  ;; When value is a key
  (for ([v values])
    (if (hash-has-key? ht v)
      (hash-set! ht v (+ (hash-ref ht v) 1))
      null))

  ;; Iterate over keys and
  ;; Create list of values 
  (for/list ([k keys])
    (hash-ref ht k)))
```

Since recursion is prohibited, explicitly looping may make for more maintainable/readable code than an implicit loop. Besides, the variations of `for` are worth knowing. Hash tables have the advantage that duplicate keys read the same value and there is no need to track the same key twice.

One of the engineering advantages of using `for` rather than `map` is that it is easier to reason about the running time. The running time for this code is `2m + n` where `m` is `keys` and `n` is `values`. Solutions using `map` will typically be `m * n`. There's nothing inherently wrong with that. But it is worth recognizing.